# NIntegrate giving a linear result for non-linear integrand

Tags: numerical-integration

I am getting this really weird error when using NIntegrate. I am trying to integrate the composition of these two functions

```
Temp[t_] := 285. - 15.*Sin[2*Pi*t/365.];
bT[Tmp_] := 5.0*Exp[-(Tmp - 290.)^2/(2*7.^2)];
Plot[bT[Temp[t]], {t, 0, 365.}]
```

[image]

This is a highly non-linear function but when trying to integrate with NIntegrate I get a linear function

```
tt[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[bT[Temp[s]], {s, 0, t}];
Plot[tt[t], {t, 0, 365.}]
```

[image]

This sounds like it is some stupid mistake, but I can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me find out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Maybe there is a hanging definition. Please try to restart the kernel with `Exit[]` and try the computations again.

Comment: Consider Plot[tt[t], {t, 50, 120.}].

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher using Exit[] worked like a charm! I am just confused as I was already using ClearAll["Global`*"]. Doesn't it also clear the hanging definitions?

Comment: Hm. `ClearAll["Global`*"]` clears only symbols in the global context. Usually, that should suffice. But sometimes, it is better to "turn it off and on again". ("It" is Mathematica's kernel in this cases.)